# Inner Spacing within Footer (fancyhdr)

Tags: spacing, fancyhdr, footer

How can I create exactly the following spaces/distances?
[image]

```
Margin from bottom to footerrule: 22mm
Distance from footerule to text: 5mm
Distance from Footerrule to top of footertext: 7mm
```

Current state:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left = 16mm,
  right = 16mm,
  textwidth = 178mm,
  top = 20mm,
  bottom= 22mm, % 22m lower bound + 5mm footer to text
  % headheight=17pt, % as per the warning by fancyhdr
  % includehead,
  % includefoot,
  heightrounded, % to avoid spurious underfull messages
  headheight=0mm,%
  headsep=0mm,%
]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Necessary packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.0}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Header and Footer Format
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \let\footruleskip\undefined %undefine footruleskip
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{black}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{5mm} % 7
\setlength{\footskip}{5mm + 0.25mm + 7mm + 2.5mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Custom Footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyfoot[L]{
  % \vfill
  \textbf{
      {\fontsize{9}{14}\selectfont SOME TITLE}
  }
}
\fancyfoot[R]{
  % \vfill
  \makebox[86mm][r]{%
       {\fontsize{9}{14}\selectfont Contact: info@website.com}
    \hfill
       {\fontsize{9}{14}\selectfont www.example.com}
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unlike the header, the footer only has a baseline, no height.  \footskip is the distance from the bottom (baseline) of the text area to the baseline of the footer.  Figure \dp\strutbox overhang below both.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved my requirements with the following code.

Define the `footskip` in `geometry`: `7mm + 1em` since I need the `7mm` space and one line of text.

```
\usepackage[%
  a4paper,%
  left = 16mm,%
  right = 16mm,%
  textwidth = 178mm,%
  top = 20mm,%
  bottom= 22mm,%
  heightrounded,% to avoid spurious underfull messages
  headheight=0mm,%
  headsep=0mm,%
  footskip=7mm+8pt,%
  % showframe
]{geometry}
```

Afterward, I corrected my `fancyhdr` settings like the following:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{7mm}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\footrule}
  {\if@fancyplain}
  {\color{gray}\if@fancyplain}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
```

I achieve the additional `5mm` between the `footrule` and the body with an extra `\vspace{5mm}` at the last element of each page (which is in my case always the same element).